# How to access the Ember Data Store from the console?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember.js-2

In Ember 2+, does anyone know how to get a reference to the Ember Store in order to troubleshoot Model mapping in the javascript console?

It was possible through `App.__container__.lookup` in Ember 1, but this doesn't exist anymore, and it's bloody hard to find documentation on this.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just use the Ember Inspector?

Comment: Well it's only good for "normally" loaded entities. I've got a model that doesn't load correctly (lots of null fields), i suspect a mapping problem but have no visible errors in the console, so i wanted to manually trigger a store load .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look in your `package.json`, you should see a `ember-export-application-global` package that's installed by default (if not, install it). This will export your application not to the global `App` object, but to a global object that's named after your app. So you might have `window.TodoList` or `window.ShoppingCart` instead of `window.App`. From there you can use this line (similar to Ember 1.x.x):

```
AppName.__container__.lookup('service:store')
```

You can also do what I do and create an [instance initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241691/using-instance-initializers-with-ember-1-12-0-and-the-ember-cli) for it:

```
export default {
    name: 'store-on-app',
    after: 'ember-data',
    initialize(instance) {
        const application = instance.container.lookup('application:main');
        const store = instance.container.lookup('service:store');
        application.set('store', store);
    }
}
```

Then you can just use `AppName.store`.

Comment: It's perfect. had to install the package because it's a migrated old ember app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to install a separate package to access your app in the console, you can do it through `window.Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES`. For example, something you can run in the console to find your app instance is:

```
var app = Ember.A(Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES).filter(n => {return n.name === 'your-app-name'})[0];
```

From here, you can access the store on the app's container as explained by @GJK

```
var store = app.__container__.lookup('service:store');
```

I used this for debugging an Ember app in production which didn't have its container registered on the `window`. I found it out by looking through the `ember-inspector` source code, since it always has access to the container.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/blob/2237dc1b4818e31a856f3348f35305b10f42f60a/ember_debug/vendor/startup-wrapper.js#L201